# How to get the status of a javaws launch in Web Server

Tags: jsp, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm trying to launch a JNLP file from my struts action, on clicking a link on a JSP. How can i get to know that the launch is successful on client side or is there any failure? If it is not successful then i need to get an indication to my JSP or struts action. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get to know that the launch is successful on client side..?

Have the JWS app. open a page at your site that is something like:

http://our.com/launchstatus.jsp?name=OurApp&code=xXn5Ha9f4

Where the `code` is specific to that request & is provided as a property in a dynamically generated JNLP file.  Any apps. for which you do not get a report back, failed for some reason.

Comment: Is there any way in the JNLP/JWS (on the client side) to report back the **bold**"status of JWS launch"**bold** (Success/Failure/Exceptions) back to my Struts action/Servlet?

Comment: As long as it reaches the `main(String[])`, it can include anything that can be encoded into an URL param.  You might even call it several times during the main, reporting progress.  But no, if the app. never reaches `main(String[])`, there is no facility to report anything back.